# Wordpress how to use shortcode to get a value from localStorage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

**Problem:**
I need to create a shortcode that contains a value extracted from a strong tag.
When I echo "document.write(localStorage.getItem('getnum'));";
the code shows the value 85.
But when I return it (the following code), the shortcode [showpoints] shows no value.
Would you please let me know how to return the value?

**Code I tried:**

```
    <?php
         ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        let getnum = $('div.elementor-widget-container p > strong').text();
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getnum'));
      });
    </script>

    <?php
    function points_show_function() {
    return "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('getnum'));</script>";
    }
    add_shortcode('showpoints', 'points_show_function');
```

**Console:**

No error

**HTML (code came from a yith point & reward plugin):**

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-c1d0790 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="c1d0790" data-element_type="widget" id="pointsid" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <p>Your credit is  <strong>85</strong> Points</p>                       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks agin Ruvee : ) Based on your instruction I stuided to manage the code and,,, one line 6, I set the value => const obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getnum'));, then I changed it to echo => function points_show_function() {$showpoint = isset($_GET['obj']); echo $showpoint; }, but it shows nothing.. And.. I also tried var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getnum'));, but still shows nothing... Would you teach me where to fix please? Thank you a lot Ruvee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You would need to set the value first so that you could get it later on! On line `6` you would need to set it.
2. Replace `return` with `echo` in your callback function.
3. You would need to call your short code by using `do_shortcode` in your template!

So your code would be something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    let getnum = $('div.elementor-widget-container p > strong').text();
    localStorage.setItem('getnum', getnum);
  });
</script>

<?php
add_shortcode('showpoints', 'points_show_function');

function points_show_function()
{
  echo "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('getnum'));</script>";
}

do_shortcode('[showpoints]');
```

This `do_shortcode('[showpoints]');` will do the magic here! So place it on your template where you want to output the value.

---

Alternative way

According to [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#example) you do not need to use `JSON.stringify` to set a single string value to `localStorage`, but just in case you can't get the first method to work, use the following code instead:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    let getnum = $('div.elementor-widget-container p > strong').text();
    localStorage.setItem('getnum', JSON.stringify(getnum));
  });
</script>

<?php
add_shortcode('showpoints', 'points_show_function');

function points_show_function()
{
  echo "<script>document.write(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getnum')));</script>";
}

do_shortcode('[showpoints]');
```

---

Another way using `return`

If you would need to `return` the value in your callback function, then use this code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    let getnum = $('div.elementor-widget-container p > strong').text();
    localStorage.setItem('getnum', JSON.stringify(getnum));
  });
</script>

<?php
add_shortcode('showpoints', 'points_show_function');

function points_show_function()
{
  return "<script>document.write(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getnum')));</script>";
}

echo do_shortcode('[showpoints]');
```

Comment: Ohh,, both works very well, thank you Ruvee : ) The only problem is I need to add the shortcode to dynamic tags, but Dynamic gtas only recognize returen value.. I tried several times but it just doesn't recognize echo value. I was wondering if you could let me know how to return the value? Thank you again Ruvee

Comment: Sure! Just updated my answer, see the last solution. You would need to use the combination of `return` **AND** `echo do_shortcode('[showpoints]');`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruvee : ) I tried the return code and it shows 85, but something strange happened.  Website shows 85, but the Dynamic tags show NaN, so I checked a inspect page. It shows "85". In detail it shows <div class="elementor-shortcode">script>document.write(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getnum')));</script>"85"</div>. I also checked Dynamic tags with code return '30';, the Dynamic tags shows 30. So... in my humble opinion, I seems it's due to the " ". If it's the case, I'm sorry but would you teach me how to thoroughly remove the "" please?

Comment: Hi Ruvee: I looked into for long and found that the echo value includes <script>document.write(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getnum')));</script>, so it doesn't work in Dynamic tags. I'm looking for a way to only extract the number without the script tags. I think it's different issue from the shortcode. Thanks a lot for your hlep Ruvee : )